# How to get Id using Jquery in MVC?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I am developing the MVC application.
I want to get the Id of the record when I click on the remove link.
In alert window I want to show record ID which I removed.

How to do this ?

```
  @model PaymentAdviceEntity.CompanyType

     <script type="text/javascript">

         $(document).ready(function () {
             $('.remove').click(function () {   
                alert(?????);         
               $(this).parent().parent().remove();   


        });          

         });

     </script>          


     <div id='InvoiceList' class='divInvoiceList span12' style='margin-bottom:5px;margin-left:0px;'>
            @if (Model != null)
       {
               <span class="span3" style="margin-left:0px;">@Html.TextBox("InvoiceId", @Model.Name , new { @onkeypress = "return isNumberKey(event)", @onblur = "CalculateNetValue()", @style = "width:75%; text-align:right;", @class = "clsInvoiceId" })</span>  

<span class="span1" style="margin-left:0px;padding-top:6px;">@Html.HiddenFor(model=>model.Id) <a href='#' style='font-size:14px;text-decoration:none;font-weight:bold;' id='lnkRemove' class='clsRemove remove'>X</a></span>

       }

    </div>
```

I can see the record ID i.e. data-id = 4 but cant get check the below HTML code after running the app.

```
<span class="span3" style="margin-left:0px;" data-id="4"><input class="clsInvoiceId valid" id="InvoiceId" name="InvoiceId" onblur="CalculateNetValue()" onkeypress="return isNumberKey(event)" style="width:75%; text-align:right;" type="text" value="asdasd"></span>
```

Comment: Why not get Id before removing or just hide instead of removing?

Comment: I think your markup is incorrect. If you use $(this).parent().parent().remove(); you'll be removing your parent div which is "InvoiceList" instead of the other span which contains the recordID

Comment: ok, I will check this out, but my first priority is to get the Id of the span...

Comment: Which one are you trying to get? Id of the span or Id of the textbox?

Comment: record Id , right now I have written this code...   `<span class="span1" style="margin-left:0px;padding-top:6px;">@Html.HiddenFor(model=>model.Id) <a href='#' style='font-size:14px;text-decoration:none;font-weight:bold;' id='lnkRemove' class='clsRemove remove'>X</a></span>`

Comment: which one of that is the record id? is it the model.id?

Answer (score 1):

```
$('.remove').click(function () {  
   var $ele = $(this).parent().parent();

   var id = $ele.attr("id");

   $ele.remove();   

   alert(id);                
});
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are talking about an ID attribute in your Model then you can simply add that in a hidden field inside your span

```
<span class="span1" style="margin-left:0px;padding-top:6px;">@Html.HiddenFor(model=>model.ID) <a href='#' style='font-size:14px;text-decoration:none;font-weight:bold;' id='lnkRemove' class='clsRemove remove'>X</a></span>
```

and access it on client side like

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
         $('.remove').click(function () {
           var id = $(this).closest("input").val();   
           $(this).parent().parent().remove();   

           alert(id);                
    });
```

EDIT

If the following HTML is being produced

```
<span class="span3" style="margin-left:0px;" data-id="4"><input class="clsInvoiceId valid" id="InvoiceId" name="InvoiceId" onblur="CalculateNetValue()" onkeypress="return isNumberKey(event)" style="width:75%; text-align:right;" type="text" value="asdasd"></span>
```

Then, you should use the following jQuery Code

```
$('.remove').click(function () {
    var id = $(this).parent().prev().attr("data-id");
    $(this).parent().parent().remove();
    alert(id);
});
```

You can see it working [here](http://jsfiddle.net/GG2kH/)

Answer (score 1):

```
$('.remove').click(function () {
     var removedId = $(this).closest('.clsInvoiceId').val();
     $(this).parent().parent().remove();   
     alert(removedId); 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATE**

If your HTML looks like this,

```
    <span class="span3" style="margin-left:0px;" data-id="4">
        <input class="clsInvoiceId valid" id="InvoiceId" name="InvoiceId" onblur="CalculateNetValue()" onkeypress="return isNumberKey(event)" style="width:75%; text-align:right;" type="text" value="asdasd">
    </span>
    <span class="span1" style="margin-left:0px;padding-top:6px;"> 
        <a href='#' style='font-size:14px;text-decoration:none;font-weight:bold;' id='lnkRemove' class='clsRemove remove'>X</a>
    </span>
```

Then, when you click the link this should get the `data-id`

```
$('.remove').live("click", function () {     
     var removedId = $(this).parent().prev().attr("data-id");
     $(this).parent().parent().remove();  
     alert(removedId);
});
```

Comment: "undefined" message is coming in alert window.

Comment: how about this? and also, its much easier for me to help you if you show me the output markup, pure HTML without razor code. I dont know what this "@Html.HiddenFor(model=>model.Id)" will produce..:/

Comment: Code look like this `<span class="span3" style="margin-left:0px;" data-id="4"><input class="clsInvoiceId valid" id="InvoiceId" name="InvoiceId" onblur="CalculateNetValue()" onkeypress="return isNumberKey(event)" style="width:75%; text-align:right;" type="text" value="asdasd"></span>` I can see the data-id but failed while displaying in alert window.

Comment: `parent().parent()` will not work: the other span is a sibling. Either put the `data-id` in the span surrounding the `a` tag or navigate to it using `siblings()` or `closest()` as already suggested in other answers

Answer (score 1):

You must put the ID somewhere in your HTML mark-up, since, once in client-land, you don't have access to the model anymore.

Basically you can use the new `data-` HTML5 attributes:

```
<span class="span1" data-id="@Model.ID"> <-- this is the important bit
  <a href='#' id='lnkRemove' class='clsRemove remove'>X</a>
</span>
```

then:

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
     $('.remove').click(function () {   
       alert($(this).parent().data("id")); // here we read the data-id...
       $(this).parent().parent().remove();   
     });          
 });
```

Comment: Can you check the generated HTML? it should have `data-id="..."` with the ID number in there. Make sure you go up using `parent()` the correct number of times... I used parent() only once and put the `data-id` on the span...

Comment: yes data-id is coming in HTML code, but it showing the "undefined" message in alert.

Comment: Can you create a fiddle? This one is working as it should: http://jsfiddle.net/9Meg9/